# Html Read More code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating **Read More** Code in Html.

Everything is working fine. but when I click on **Read More** . then it displays data along with **text-ellipsis** property ie. **...***. I want **Read More** text to be center in next line which I am getting but it displays **...** also.

[image: output I want]

[image: Output I m getting.]

There is three dots ***...*** after **mauris** text.

How can I remove that.

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var showChar = 400;
        var ellipsestext = "...";
        var moretext = "Read More";
        var lesstext = "Read Less";
        $('.more').each(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();

            if(content.length > showChar) {

                var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

                var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span><div class="text-center margin_top_10"><a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></div></span>';

                $(this).html(html);
            }

        });

        $(".morelink").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                $(this).removeClass("less");
                $(this).html(moretext);
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("less");
                $(this).html(lesstext);
            }
            $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
            $(this).prev().toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```css
.comment {
  width: 93%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
a.morelink {
  outline: none;
  color: #5bc0de !important;
}
.morecontent span {
  display: none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row b-t padding_top_bottom_10">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
<div class="comment more font_size_14"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis,
  quam ligula sodales orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus.
  Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
  blandit id luctus felis convallis.
  Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
  Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis,
  quam ligula sodales orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus.
  Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
  blandit id luctus felis convallis.
  Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
  Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `$(".moreelipses").toggle();` in read more button onClick

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var showChar = 400;
        var ellipsestext = "...";
        var moretext = "Read More";
        var lesstext = "Read Less";
        $('.more').each(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();

            if(content.length > showChar) {

                var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

                var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span><div class="text-center margin_top_10"><a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></div></span>';

                $(this).html(html);
            }

        });

        $(".morelink").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                $(this).removeClass("less");
                $(this).html(moretext);
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("less");
                $(this).html(lesstext);
            }
            $(".moreelipses").toggle();
            $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
            $(this).prev().toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```css
.comment {
  width: 93%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
a.morelink {
  outline: none;
  color: #5bc0de !important;
}
.morecontent span {
  display: none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row b-t padding_top_bottom_10">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
<div class="comment more font_size_14"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis,
  quam ligula sodales orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus.
  Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
  blandit id luctus felis convallis.
  Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
  Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis,
  quam ligula sodales orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus.
  Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
  blandit id luctus felis convallis.
  Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
  Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello.. in your code there is space when I click on read more.   i get **adip piscing** instead of **adippiscing**

Comment: remove `&nbsp;` you will get rid of the space

Answer (score 0):

Just change ellipsestext="..." to ""

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var showChar = 400;
        var ellipsestext = "";
        var moretext = "Read More";
        var lesstext = "Read Less";
        $('.more').each(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();

            if(content.length > showChar) {

                var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

                var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span><div class="text-center margin_top_10"><a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></div></span>';

                $(this).html(html);
            }

        });

        $(".morelink").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                $(this).removeClass("less");
                $(this).html(moretext);
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("less");
                $(this).html(lesstext);
            }
            $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
            $(this).prev().toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: i want **...** to be there

Answer (score -1):

Use `readmore.js` jquery plugin.

Get it here : http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/