# Read more script and side by side divs not working together properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882236/html-read-more-code) on how to set up a "read more" for text sections, as well as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882236/html-read-more-code) to set up two side by side divs, I've been having an issue where the left floating div works fine - clicking "Read More" shows the rest of the text in the div, and vice versa for "Read Less". However, the second div does not work as intended - clicking "Read More" hides the text of the second div while also changing the ellipsis of the first div.

To make it more clear:

```
//Script for Read More/Read Less
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var showChar = 200;
        var ellipsestext = "...";
        var moretext = "Read More";
        var lesstext = "Read Less";
        $('.more').each(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();

            if(content.length > showChar) {

                var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

                var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span><div class="text-center margin_top_10"><a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></div></span>';

                $(this).html(html);
            }

        });

        $(".morelink").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                $(this).removeClass("less");
                $(this).html(moretext);
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("less");
                $(this).html(lesstext);
            }
            $(".moreelipses").toggle();
            $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
            $(this).prev().toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
    .comment {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    a.morelink {
        outline: none;
        color: #5bc0de !important;
    }
    .morecontent span {
        display: none;

    }
</style>

//First Div
<div class="container" style="width:620px; float:left;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="comment more col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
            <p class="comment more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
//Second Div
<div class="container" style="width:620px; float:right;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="comment more col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
            <p class="comment more">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both">
</div>
```

**Results:**

- If both divs are not expanded, both show up fine.
- If div 1 is expanded and div 2 is not, div 1's text expands as expected. Div 2 stays the same.
- If div 2 is expanded and div 1 is not, div 2's text stays contracted. Both div's ellipsis (...) disappear.
- If both divs are expanded, div 1's text expands as expected, div 2's text stays contracted. Div 1 still shows its ellipsis when it's not meant to.

Comment: Posting a fiddle always helps: https://jsfiddle.net/bgssveqq/

Comment: First one doesn't replicate my issue - there's only a single Read More link, not one for each div. While the second one fixes this, in both jsfiddles, Read More only hides the text, and doesn't expand it.

Comment: I am sorry I just posted the fiddle for your code... I am working on fixing it now :). So clicking on the Read More should expand that div only and clicking on Read Less should collapse and display the `...` for that div only right?

Comment: Yes. And each Read More/Read Less should not affect the other div (eg. if div 2's Read More is clicked, div 1's ... should not be affected).

Comment: It doesn't do it correctly - instead of going from contracted text + ellipsis + Read More to expanded text + no ellipsis + Read Less, it's going from no text + Read More to contracted text + ellipsis + Read Less.

Comment: Ok got it... it's a bit confusing. Let me work more on it.

Comment: Why do you have span inside a span?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bgssveqq/3/ Almost there... now to remove the extra letter. Am I close?

Comment: Extra letter? That one looks about right.

Comment: The letter before the `...` is extra.... Working on removing it. Maybe you give it a go also :)... Notice how to I removed the extra span and also you don't have to `return false` at the end if you use `javascript:void(0);` for the href of the link.

Comment: Here is the final version: https://jsfiddle.net/bgssveqq/4/. The extra letter is still showing. I can work on it later on. You can just maybe try to remove the extra letter.

Comment: I think you tried to copy this: https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA... That is working.... use that instead.

Comment: I fixed your code with the extra letter. It was `var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);` - remove the -1 from showChar. @Si8 do you mind posting it as an answer to allow me to mark it as such?

Comment: Awesome... I will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed a tidying up with the code...

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bgssveqq/5/

partial JS:

```
$(".morelink").on("click", function() {
          if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                $(this).removeClass("less");
                $(this).html(moretext);
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass("less");
                $(this).html(lesstext);
            }
            $(this).parent().parent().children("p").children(".moreelipses").toggle();
            $(this).parent().parent().children("p").children(".morecontent").toggle();
        });
```